# How to set a relative position/size to the screen for elements in CSS/HTML?

Tags: html, css, web

I would like to set a relative position values to a screen for an HTML elements.
How can I do so?

I know you can for example the attribute *width :50%*, but can I do the same for positioning?

thanks

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Could you tell us what you've actually tried?

Comment: I'm trying to build an backgammon game, and I want that my board game will look the same on all the screens, any suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - you could use a percentage for the margin and padding attributes.

```
.element {
margin-left: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use it for position, for margin or padding.

`#Container
    {
    width:50%;
    margin-left:25%;
    padding-left:10%;
    }`